# ffmpeg: Encode a video that has creation_time recognized by android

Tags: video, ffmpeg, android, video-conversion

I use ffmpeg to convert some of my videos which were recorded on an android phone (samsung galaxy s9+):

```
ffmpeg -i src.mp4 -metadata creation_time="2013-05-02 22:01:04" -c:v libx265 -crf 24 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -b:a 160k target.mp4
```

My goal is, to keep metadata after that reencode, especially the creation_time.

When I look into MediaInfo, the creation_time seems to be correct. The date that I specified appears in all streams and even in the container part.

However, if I copy the file to my Samsung, in the gallery, it won't be shown with that date, but with the modification date (file level) instead.

So, when I change the file's modification date, it changes on android.

When I take an mp4 file that has been recorded by the phone's camera, and change the file's modification date there, the gallery on the phone still shows the original date.

So, there must be something in the way, how the samsung camera stores the date information, or maybe a special way how to encode with ffmpeg, so creation_time gets recognized by android.

Comparing both files with MediaInfo and looking at the timestamps, I can't find anything that could be missing on the encoded file.

Does somebody have an idea here?

Comment: Please show the complete output for the two files from MediaInfo, or `ffmpeg -i <input>`.